# How to implement Emission with MSL

Tags: objective-c, shader, metal

I have been studying the Metal API (newbie here) and working with the examples and documentation to create a 3D animation in my iOS app. I know I can use SceneKit but for the moment I want to understand and learn how Metal API works.

One of the [examples](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/using_function_specialization_to_build_pipeline_variants) from Apple implements a decent number of textures mapping for the object, but the emission texture is missing. After a bit of study I came with a solution like this:

```c
float3 computeDiffuse(LightingParameters parameters)
{
    float3 diffuseRawValue = float3(((1.0/PI) * parameters.baseColor) * (1.0 - parameters.metalness));
    return diffuseRawValue * parameters.nDotl * parameters.ambientOcclusion;
}

float3 computeSpecular(LightingParameters parameters)
{
    float specularRoughness = parameters.roughness * (1.0 - parameters.metalness) + parameters.metalness;

    float Ds = Distribution(parameters.nDoth, specularRoughness);

    float3 Cspec0 = float3(1.0f);
    float3 Fs = float3(mix(float3(Cspec0), float3(1), Fresnel(parameters.hDotl)));
    float alphaG = sqr(specularRoughness * 0.5 + 0.5);
    float Gs = Geometry(parameters.nDotl, alphaG) * Geometry(parameters.nDotv, alphaG);

    float3 specularOutput = (Ds * Gs * Fs * parameters.irradiatedColor)
      * (1.0 + parameters.metalness * float3(parameters.baseColor))
      + float3(parameters.metalness)
      * parameters.irradiatedColor
      * float3(parameters.baseColor);

    return specularOutput * parameters.ambientOcclusion;
}

float3 computeEmissive(LightingParameters parameters)
{
  float3 diffuseRawValue = float3(((1.0/PI) * parameters.emissiveColor));
  return diffuseRawValue;
}

//...

fragment float4
fragmentLighting(ColorInOut in [[stage_in]],
                 constant AAPLUniforms         & uniforms         [[ buffer(AAPLBufferIndexUniforms) ]],
                 constant AAPLMaterialUniforms & materialUniforms [[ buffer(AAPLBufferIndexMaterialUniforms) ]],
                 texture2d<float>   baseColorMap         [[ texture(AAPLTextureIndexBaseColor),        function_constant(has_base_color_map) ]],
                 texture2d<float>   normalMap            [[ texture(AAPLTextureIndexNormal),           function_constant(has_normal_map) ]],
                 texture2d<float>   metallicMap          [[ texture(AAPLTextureIndexMetallic),         function_constant(has_metallic_map) ]],
                 texture2d<float>   roughnessMap         [[ texture(AAPLTextureIndexRoughness),        function_constant(has_roughness_map) ]],
                 texture2d<float>   ambientOcclusionMap  [[ texture(AAPLTextureIndexAmbientOcclusion), function_constant(has_ambient_occlusion_map) ]],
                 texture2d<float>   emissiveMap          [[ texture(AAPLTextureIndexEmissive),         function_constant(has_emissive_map) ]],
                 texturecube<float> irradianceMap        [[ texture(AAPLTextureIndexIrradianceMap),    function_constant(has_irradiance_map)]])
{
    float4 final_color = float4(0);

    LightingParameters parameters = calculateParameters(in,
                                                        uniforms,
                                                        materialUniforms,
                                                        baseColorMap,
                                                        normalMap,
                                                        metallicMap,
                                                        roughnessMap,
                                                        ambientOcclusionMap,
                                                        emissiveMap,
                                                        irradianceMap);

    final_color = float4(computeSpecular(parameters) + computeDiffuse(parameters) + computeEmissive(parameters), 1.0f);

    return final_color;

}
```

This code above makes the object get slightly white, which is not the desired effect.

Note the line `computeSpecular(parameters) + computeDiffuse(parameters) + computeEmissive(parameters)`, in the original source code `computeEmissive(parameters)` does not exist, that's something that I have implemented trying to make the color more intense, probably this is totally wrong and what I have should be doing is to change the contrast, brightness and luminance, but I am not sure how to do this.

I am probably doing everything wrong, I am open to any suggestion. :)

Thank you.

Comment: final_color = actually float4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0) maximum where the first 3 of those `1.0` are given by float3. what about multiplication of all of them by 0.5 and see what happens

Comment: making color more intense can mean a lot of different things.. if think of contrast thats just how fast a value ramps up to 1.0 and brightness as the average level in colors close to 1.0. If you exceed 1.0 thats maximum you end up with all white.

Comment: you can show also your extension of struct LightingParameters to see what type is .emissiveColor and so on.. and you could melt the shader functions computeEmissive and computeDiffuse together.

Comment: @OlSen It's working! Thank you. I will keep it open for further discussion.